# Multivariable Chain Rule for two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Using the general chain rule compute $dw/dr$ for:

$w=x^2+y^2, x=rs, y=r+2s$

answer should be in terms of r and s

I am stuck. I know this is easy and I'm sure someone will be mean about this but I'm not exactly sure how to do this with the two variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you have $u=u(x,y)$ and $x=x(\ldots,t,\ldots)$, $y=y(\ldots,t,\ldots)$  -that is,$x$ and $y$ are functions of some variables, being $t$ one of them-, the Chain Rule states that

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\cdot \frac{d x}{d t} +\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{d y}{d t}$$

Or, with a simpler notation,

$$u_t=u_xx_t+u_yy_t$$

The explanation is an extension of the single-variable case: You have to multiply the dependent change rates up to $t$ ($u$ depends on $x$ and $x$ depends on $t$), AND you need to add up all independent change rates (changes on $x$ are independent of changes on $y$). This can be extended for functions $u,x,t$ with any number of variables.

---

In this case, we have: 
$$w=x^2+y^2,\qquad x=rs,\qquad y=r+2s$$

Then,
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
w_r&=&w_xx_r+w_yy_r\\
&=&2x\frac{dx}{dr}+2y\frac{dy}{dr}\\
\end{array}$$

But 
$$x=rs\to\frac{dx}{dr}=s$$
$$y=r+2s\to\frac{dy}{dr}=1$$

So
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
&=&2x\frac{dx}{dr}+2y\frac{dy}{dr}\\
&=&2(rs)(s)+2(r+2s)(1)\\
&=&2rs^2+2r+4s
\end{array}$$

Using the same procedure, you can find $w_s$.

---

Note: a thing I have noticed a lot of times is that, for higher-order derivatives, people make mistakes because they fail to understand that the derivatives of $u$ are also functions of $(x,y)$, so you need to use the Chain Rule again:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} u_t = u_{tt}&=&\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(u_xx_t)+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(u_yy_t)\\
&=&\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(u_x)\cdot x_t+u_x\cdot\frac{d}{d t}x_t+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(u_y)\cdot y_t+u_y\cdot\frac{d}{d t}(y_t)\\
&=&(u_{xx}x_t+u_{xy}y_t)\cdot x_t+u_xx_{tt}+(u_{yx}x_t+u_{yy}y_t)\cdot y_t+u_yy_{tt}\\
&=&u_{xx}x_t^2+u_{xy}y_tx_t+u_{yx}x_ty_t+u_{yy}y_t^2+u_xx_{tt}+u_yy_{tt}\\
\end{array}$$

And often we have functions that meet $u_{yx}=u_{xy}$, so
$$u_{tt}=u_{xx}x_t^2+2u_{xy}y_tx_t+u_{yy}y_t^2+u_xx_{tt}+u_yy_{tt}$$

Comment: THANK YOU!! that actually makes a lot of sense.

Comment: You're welcome! If you liked the answer, could you accept it? Also, if soemthing's confusing, please tell me to further explain.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the chain rule, $\frac{dw}{dr}$ should look like this:

## $\frac{dw}{dr} = 2x\frac{dx}{dr} + 2y\frac{dy}{dr}$

Then we can find $\frac{dx}{dr}$ and $\frac{dy}{dr}$ from their given equations.

Comment: but isn't $dx/dr=0$, and is $dy/dr$

Comment: @JenniferLoud No. dx/dr is the derivative of $x(r)=rs$ w.r.t $r$. Thus $x'(r)=s$